# how to export t-tests results from r? can I add a new column to the dataframe containing the resulting p-values?

Tags: r, loops

I managed to run a while loop to run t-tests comparing each row (see code below) & the results print out in the console. **Now I am wondering how to export the t-test results from r? Is it possible to add a new column to the original dataframe with the t-test & p-value results?**

```
  `a<-1 #row1 
   while a<11 #number of rows(10)+1 
   {
b<-t.test(Large_Intestine_WT[a,],Large_Intestine_ALL_MUTANT[a,],paired=FALSE)
  print(rownames(Large_Intestine_WT[a,])) print (b) a<-a+1 
}`
```

E.g.

**dataframe1:** 
`dput(Large_Intestine_WT[1:10, 1:6])`
structure(list(SKCO1_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(50.66, 0, 63.12, 5.57, 
9.82, 0, 0.03, 59.69, 54.33, 15.95), SW1463_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(11.99, 
0, 158.81, 4.21, 5.61, 0.98, 0.16, 65.32, 69.42, 13.85), C2BBE1_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(90.01, 
0.07, 251.76, 3.75, 21.49, 0, 0.02, 135.1, 51.98, 23.82), LS123_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(41.13, 
0.02, 83.12, 3.45, 14.64, 0.08, 0.25, 62.92, 14.1, 17.93), LS513_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(15.75, 
0, 58.3, 7.28, 12.55, 0.02, 0.01, 46.24, 30.43, 14.89), MDST8_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(16.32, 
0, 76.72, 2.69, 16.29, 0.01, 11.71, 86.57, 5.35, 19.58)), row.names = c("ENSG00000000003.10", 
"ENSG00000000005.5", "ENSG00000000419.8", "ENSG00000000457.9", 
"ENSG00000000460.12", "ENSG00000000938.8", "ENSG00000000971.11", 
"ENSG00000001036.9", "ENSG00000001084.6", "ENSG00000001167.10"
), class = "data.frame")

**dataframe2:** 
`dput(Large_Intestine_ALL_MUTANT[1:10, 1:6])`
structure(list(SW948_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(30.3, 0.86, 117.62, 
6.54, 12.54, 0.01, 0.01, 49.54, 44.32, 24.88), CCK81_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(33.6, 
0.29, 117.17, 5.41, 15.02, 0.09, 0.06, 112.3, 51.45, 15.18), 
    RKO_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(11.89, 0.02, 153.59, 1.43, 12.71, 
    0, 0.13, 56.71, 15.72, 21.12), HCT116_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(26.62, 
    0, 108.14, 5.4, 23.62, 0, 0.04, 62.43, 52.36, 27.08), T84_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(56.72, 
    0.31, 75.88, 5.18, 16.03, 0.01, 0.04, 111.02, 41.39, 18.14
    ), CW2_LARGE_INTESTINE = c(36.58, 0.32, 44.1, 3.44, 7.57, 
    0.12, 0.1, 37.96, 46.32, 20.36)), row.names = c("ENSG00000000003.10", 
"ENSG00000000005.5", "ENSG00000000419.8", "ENSG00000000457.9", 
"ENSG00000000460.12", "ENSG00000000938.8", "ENSG00000000971.11", 
"ENSG00000001036.9", "ENSG00000001084.6", "ENSG00000001167.10"
), class = "data.frame")

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, please add sample data with `dput(head(df,n))`. Do this for both datasets for better reproducibility.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This can be done with a simple `for` loop, and it would be easy to show you how after you create a [mcve] as @NelsonGon suggests: If you simply [edit] your question to include the output of the R commands `dput(head(dataframe1))` and `dput(head(dataframe2))`, we can easily recreate your data in our R session